# saving data safely before Activity is destroyed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, activity-lifecycle

i need to save some crucial importance data when user closes my app. i prefere to do this in `Activity`'s `onPause()`, as it is the latest method guaranteed to be called before the application is destroyed no matter what is the reason of its destruction. however, i save the data in a database, so i use an `AsyncTask`. from my `AsyncTask`, when it's finished, i call a callback method on my `Activity` reference i have saved in the `AsyncTask` before, where i put some variables to `SharedPreferences` indicating that the data has been successfully put to database.

**my question is:** is the `AsyncTask` guaranteed to finish and the callback to be called on an alive `Activity` reference before it gets destroyed? If not, how to ensure that data is written to database before `Activity` is destroyed?

Comment: Have you tried any code before? If so please get me the code here i will let you know the issue

Comment: it's not an issue. i'm just asking a technical question about application behaviour. the situation is described in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to implement a `CallBack` method to save in your `SharedPreferences` that you have updated the `Database`.

You can simply, if you really need a database for your info, create a flag in your `SharedPreferences` called *isDataExistToLoad*

This flag has to be initially `False`, and within the `Thread` that will store your info into the Database set it to `True`.

```
public void updateUserStatus(ArrayList<Object> data){
    try{
         DBController.save(data);
         SharedPReferencesController.setDataExistToLoad(true);
    }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         SharedPReferencesController.setDataExistToLoad(false);
    }
}
```

Whenever you open your app, check on this flag. If it is `True` go load from database then set it to `False`. If it is `False` leave it as it is because the previous transaction was not successfully done.

> **My question is:** is the AsyncTask guaranteed to finish and the callback
>   to be called on an alive Activity reference before it gets destroyed?
>   If not, how to ensure that data is written to database before Activity
>   is destroyed?

**My Answer is:** Part of the `AsyncTask` runs in a separate Thread which is DoInBackground and you cannot ensure that the Activity will still be survived until it is done. If you tried to perform any other task in `postExcute()` which runs on UITread after finishing the background thread work. Your app might crash. That's why I don't recommend that.

Comment: i need all transactions to be successfully done, that's why i have written this question.

Comment: The method `Save` that will store your data should `Throw` exception in case of any failure happened. In this way you will ensure that all the transactions have been done successfully. @Salivan

Comment: but the callback is a very comfortable think in my situation. i just need somebody to tell me whether the `Activity` is going to survive until the `AsyncTask` finishes so i can be sure the callback is called.

Comment: @Salivan Part of the `AsyncTask` runs in a separate `Thread`  which is `DoInBackground` and you cannot ensure that the `Activity will still be survived. If you tried to perform any other task in `postExcute()` which runs on UITread. Your app might crash. That's why I don't recommend that.

Comment: @Salivan When you use `Try/Catch` and edit the preference at the end of the `Try` this will ensure that all the previous code has to be successfully done without any exception before editing the preferences :)

Comment: but if `Activity` is destroyed then i have no `Context` for my `SharedPreferences`... how to use it in my `AsyncTask` then?

Comment: @Salivan don't use the `AsyncTask` use a normal `Thread` and you can use the `ApplicationContext` instead of the `Activity`

Comment: why can't i use an `AsyncTask`? i can pass an `ApplicationContext` for later use.

Comment: @Salivan The main function of the AsyncTask to is communicate with an API or perform any HTTP request from the UI thread (Activity or Fragment). That's why it provide you with `onPreExcute` to show your progressBar for example and `postExcute` to hide the progress and display the data on the UI

Comment: If your question is can I pass the `ApplicationContext`? As long as it is a context, then you can pass it. But this is not how you should use it @Salivan

Comment: how should i use it then?

Comment: new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Your code her
            }
        });

Answer (score 1):

The `ASyncTask` executes in background parallely to the main thread. In case if the  Activity is closed, still the `ASyncTask` continues to execute till end. And it need not to return the control to the main process.

So, you can surely use this method of saving data before closing the application.

*I am not sure whether after `onPause` of Activity (ie; when `onPause()` callback is called) you might be able to use the `share-preference`, feature. So, you should handle it on the backbutton or some event in `onCreate()`*

Comment: i know what you mean, but i would like to know whether the `Activity` survives while `AsyncTask` executes and whether the callback will be called.

Comment: When you close the activity, the activity gets destroyed, but sill the ASyncTask continues to execute till end.

Comment: No, Activity doesn't survives when it is destroyed, even then the ASyncTask continues to execute